# PWA problem with Vue3+service worker+keep-alive

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vuejs3

I have a problem with Vue3+service worker+keep-alive.

I use keep-live in template

```
 <q-page-container>
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive :include="['WorkPage']">
      <component :is="Component" :key="$route.fullPath"/>
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
</q-page-container>
```

create queue

```
createWorkQueue = new Queue('createWorkQueue', {
    onSync: async ( {queue} ) => {     
      let entry    
      while (entry = await queue.shiftRequest()) {
        try {
          await fetch(entry.request);
          const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages-work');
          channel.postMessage({msg: 'offline-work-uploaded'});         
        } catch (error) {
          await queue.unshiftRequest(entry);
          throw error;
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

addEventListener('fetch'

```
 self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
      if (event.request.url.endsWith('/api/ins_new_work')) {          
        const bgSyncLogic = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await fetch(event.request.clone())
            return response
          } catch (error) {
            await createWorkQueue.pushRequest({request: event.request})
            return error
          }
        }
        event.respondWith(bgSyncLogic())
    }
})
```

when in offline I send form - createWorkQueue.pushRequest hangs to 5 minutes

if I delete from keep-alive - WorkPage - then pushRequest works well

but I need keep-alive page. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found!!

I use IndexedDB library and for show offline message I read from DB information

```
const db = await openDB('workbox-background-sync')
```

but in first time - table 'requests' don't create

I insert next code

```
const db = await openDB('workbox-background-sync', undefined, { upgrade(db) { db.createObjectStore('requests') }})
```

and works well